# Как добавить уже имеющиеся на пк файлы в zip архив при помощи логики java\groovy?

Tags: java, jmeter, groovy

Есть код, необходимо за время одной итерации записать еще 3 файла в архив, они статичные, не нуждаются в параметризации.

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

def destination = new java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File('request' + ${__Random(100000,200000,)} + '.zip')), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
destination.putNextEntry(new java.util.zip.ZipEntry(prev.getSampleLabel() + '.xml'))
destination << prev.getSamplerData().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

destination.close()
```

Пробовал добавить таким способом

```
List<String> filePaths = Arrays.asList("/absolute/path/file1.txt", "/absolute/path/file2.txt");
String zipPath = "/absolute/path/output.zip";

try (ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipPath))) {
    for (String filePath : filePaths) {
        File fileToZip = new File(filePath);
        zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileToZip.getName()));
        Files.copy(fileToZip.toPath(), zipOut);
    }
}
```

Но видимо логика не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, "логика" не подходит потому что, видимо, логики в ваших действиях нет. Копирование кода из интернета без понимания что этот код делает - не лучший способ освоить язык программирования.

Код нормально работает сам по себе (создание нового архива) если добавить соответствующие [импорты](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_imports):

```
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream
import java.nio.file.Files
```

Если вы хотите **добавить** файлы в **уже существующий архив** - "логика" не будет работать потому что это невозможно на уровне API Java, вам нужно открыть "старый" архив, вытащить оттуда все [ZipEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html), добавить новые и либо перезаписать предыдущий файл или сохранить под новым именем. Или использовать сторонние библиотеки типа [TrueZip](https://christian-schlichtherle.bitbucket.io/truezip/) или [7-Zip-JBinding](https://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/)

Проще будет добавить сразу все одним махом в один архив в [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-templates)

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

def destination = new java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File('request' + ${__Random(100000,200000,)} + '.zip')), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
destination.putNextEntry(new java.util.zip.ZipEntry(prev.getSampleLabel() + '.xml'))
destination << prev.getSamplerData().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

def files = ['/absolute/path/file1.txt', '/absolute/path/file2.txt']

files.each { filename ->
    def file = new File(filename)
    destination.putNextEntry(new java.util.zip.ZipEntry(file.getName()))
    destination << file.bytes
}


destination.close()
```